# Why can't NSFIleManager -fileExistsAtPath not find an existing file when path is correct?

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, nsfilemanager, ios8.1

I know that the iOS Simulator is found in a different directory each time it is run; with that in mind, I have this code which gives me the directory of the Core Data sqlite files:

```
//  find current directory for saori.sqlite
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]firstObject];
NSString *sqliteFilePath  = [[documentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Application Support/SalonBook/saori.sqlite"] absoluteString];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sqliteFilePath])
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];  //  set stack, etc to 'nil'
else  {
    NSLog(@"\n\n-->sqlite files not found");  // log message "unable to find sqlite files
    return;
}
```

This is the printout of the sqliteFilePath object:

```
Printing description of sqliteFilePath:
file:///Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/C8FF20F0-41E4-4F26-AB06-1F29936C2208/Library/Application%20Support/SalonBook/saori.sqlite
```

And this is the image of the file from Finder:
[image]

The problem is: I go to the *sqliteFilePath* and the saori.sqlite file is indeed there!  Why is **-fileExistsAtPath** failing?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. Legitimate question with content. +1.

Comment: I'm experiencing almost-similar. It seems if I store as path, then convert to absolute URL, it fails. But if I store absolute string, then don't use fileURLWithPath, but instead urlWithName: it succeeds, thought it would interchange so long as I'm on the correct half of it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it is still a URL. A file path doesn't have a protocol, so the prefix of your path `file:///` is invalid and can't be resolved. Since an invalid path doesn't contain any files, `fileExistsAtPath:` returns `NO`.

Not to worry though, instead of calling `absoluteString` on the URL object, you can just call `path` instead and it will return the path.

Comment: Not working... can you give me an example of what you are referring to when you say "just call path"?  (taking my statement, what would it look like?)  Sorry for the lame question, but I don't see how it would work... SD

Comment: @spokane-dude Instead of were you call `absoluteString`, call `path` instead.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  That did it... I saw the *path* statement in some of the examples I was trying to follow, but there was nothing in the iOS docs where I could find the explaination... thanks again!

Comment: @spokane-dude Cheers! Just to clarify this, `absoluteString` simply returns the complete URL, but a a string. `path` merely returns the path of the URL, which doesn't contain things like protocol and the like. For file URLs, this is exactly what you want if you can't work the the file URL directly.

Comment: Fantastic answer... I appreciate you taking the time to explain it to me.  Cheers to you too!  :D